# Convert decimal to base K

Tags: beginner, rust

Problem statement: Write a program that takes two command-line arguments `number` and `k`. The program should convert `number` to base `k`. Assume the base is between 2 and 16 inclusive. For bases greater than 10, use the letters A through F to represent the digits 10 through 15, respectively.

This is one of my self-imposed challenges in Rust to become better at it. The problem was taken from [Sedgewick Exercise 1.3.21](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/home/).

Here is my code:

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let arguments: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let mut number: u32 = arguments[1].parse().unwrap();
    let k: u32 = arguments[2].parse().unwrap();
    
    let number_original: u32 = number;
    let mut largest_power: u32 = 1;
    let mut kary: String = String::new();

    while largest_power <= number/k {
        largest_power *= k;
    }

    while largest_power > 0 {
        if largest_power > number {
            kary.push_str(&format!("{}", "0"));
        } else {
            let dividend: u32 = number/largest_power;

            if number/largest_power < 10 {
                kary.push_str(&format!("{}", dividend.to_string())); 
                number -= dividend*largest_power;
            }

            else if number/largest_power == 10 {kary.push_str(&format!("{}", "A")); number -= dividend*largest_power;}
            else if number/largest_power == 11 {kary.push_str(&format!("{}", "B")); number -= dividend*largest_power;}
            else if number/largest_power == 12 {kary.push_str(&format!("{}", "C")); number -= dividend*largest_power;}
            else if number/largest_power == 13 {kary.push_str(&format!("{}", "D")); number -= dividend*largest_power;}
            else if number/largest_power == 14 {kary.push_str(&format!("{}", "E")); number -= dividend*largest_power;}
            else if number/largest_power == 15 {kary.push_str(&format!("{}", "F")); number -= dividend*largest_power;}
        }

        largest_power /= k;
    }

    match k {
        2..=16 => println!("The number {} at base {} is represented with {}.", number_original, k, kary),
        _ => panic!("Base must be between 2 and 16."),
    }
}
```

Is there any way that I can improve my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Don't unwrap

Panicking is not a good way to handle errors. Rather provide an error message in case of an `Err` and exit the program gracefully.

## Use libraries

If you'd use e.g. `clap` you can let it parse the CLI arguments for you as the desired data type (`u32` in your case) and gracefully handle the respective errors.
There's also [`radix_fmt`](https://docs.rs/radix_fmt/1.0.0/radix_fmt/) available to do the conversion to any base.

## Use expressive variable names

The name `kary` is misleading. It sounds like a person's name. If you're referring to `k-ary` numbers, maybe rename it to `k_ary`. Though a less technical term such as `digits` should also suffice and might be more widely understood.

## Use `rustfmt` or `cargo fmt`

... to format your code with a standardized style.

## Validate your input.

Running the program e.g. with a base `1` results in an infinite loop.
Invalid input as base-1 should be caught early.
Similarly base-0 inputs panic the program.

## Don't `panic!()`

If you encounter an error use e.g. `eprintln!()` to print an error message and use `std::process::exit()` to exit the program with a possibly nonzero return code.

## Suggested:

`src/main.rs`

```rust
use clap::Parser;
use radix_fmt::radix;
use std::ops::RangeInclusive;
use std::process::exit;

const VALID_BASES: RangeInclusive<u8> = 2..=36;

#[derive(Debug, Parser)]
struct Args {
    #[arg(index = 1)]
    number: u32,
    #[arg(index = 2)]
    base: u8,
}

fn main() {
    let args = Args::parse();

    if !VALID_BASES.contains(&args.base) {
        eprintln!(
            "Base must be in {}..={}",
            VALID_BASES.start(),
            VALID_BASES.end()
        );
        exit(1);
    }

    println!(
        "Number {} in base {} is: {}",
        args.number,
        args.base,
        radix(args.number, args.base)
    );
}
```

`Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "bases"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
clap = { version = "4.3.11", features = ["derive"] }
radix_fmt = "1.0.0"
```

Comment: I would not print the debug format of the range. Debug format is intended for programmers, and it may change without warning. It is better to use a custom printing.